sending solana between wallets (using jito)
I'm creating a bot to send solana quickly and simultaneously (I tried to apply JITO). So I created the code below, it creates the TX but it doesn't execute, I would like to know what I should change, what I can do and what doesn't work in this case.
I was able to make the transaction via RPC Solana, so I ended up combining the 2 ideas, I don't know if it is valid, or something that cannot happen.
```    
client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/")

def create_tx_bundles(send_keypair_wallet: str, receiver_keypair_wallet: str, amount:float):
    send_keypair = Keypair.from_base58_string(send_keypair_wallet)
    receiver_keypair = Keypair.from_base58_string(receiver_keypair_wallet)
    latest_blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash

    disponivel = client.get_balance(send_keypair.pubkey()).value

    ix = transfer(
        TransferParams(
            from_pubkey=send_keypair.pubkey(),
            to_pubkey=receiver_keypair.pubkey(),
            lamports=int(disponivel * (amount/100))
        )
    )

    msg = MessageV0.try_compile(
        payer=send_keypair.pubkey(),
        instructions=[ix],
        address_lookup_table_accounts=[],
        recent_blockhash=latest_blockhash,
    )
    print(msg)
    tx = VersionedTransaction(msg, [send_keypair])
    # signedTx
    return tx


transactions = [
    {
        "send_keypair": "example sendkey",
        "receiver_keypair":"example receivekey",
        "amount": 18.45,
    },
    # {
    #     "send_keypair": msg['walletfund']['wallet'],
    #     "receiver_keypair": msg['wallet1']['wallet'],
    #     "amount": msg['wallet1']['parte'],
    # },
]


encodedSignedTransactions = []
txSignatures = []

# Access transaction data using its index in the loop
for index, transaction in enumerate(transactions):
    signedTx = create_tx_bundles(transaction["send_keypair"],transaction["receiver_keypair"],transaction["amount"])
    print(signedTx)
    encodedSignedTransactions.append(base58.b58encode(bytes(signedTx)).decode())
    txSignatures.append(str(signedTx.signatures[0]))

jito_response = requests.post(
            "https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/bundles",
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            json={
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "id": 1,
                "method": "sendBundle",
                "params": [
                    encodedSignedTransactions
                ]
            }
        )

for i, signature in enumerate(txSignatures):
    print(f'Transaction {i}: {signature}')```


Solved about this
